# Division between two numbers of the form $u + v\sqrt 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I need to do a division $a/b$, where $a$ and $b$ are numbers of the form $u + v\sqrt 2$, and $u$ and $v$ are integers (I'll write $a = u + v\sqrt 2$ and $b = u' + v'\sqrt 2$).

What is an effective way of computing that division? That is, how can I compute that without considering the infinite decimal expansion of $\sqrt 2$?

I've heard I should have been knowing something about abstract algebra, ring theory, Euclidean domains, but, although I searched some information, I'm still too far from those fiels of mathematics, which I am going to study in some years.

The only thing I know about $a/b$ is that the result should always be of the form $p + q\sqrt 2$, where $p$ and $q$ are rational: am I wrong?

And finally, is it necessary to write $a/b = a\frac{u'-v'\sqrt 2}{(u'-v'\sqrt 2)(u'+v'\sqrt 2)}=\frac{u'-v'\sqrt 2}{u'^2-2v'^2}$, so as to get rid of the $\sqrt 2$ in the denominator? Is it right that that irrational quantity may compromise the effectiveness of the division operation?

Comment: You are asking whether one **needs to** put $\frac{u+v\sqrt{2}}{u'+v'\sqrt{2}}$ in the form $p+q\sqrt{2}$ where $p$ and $q$ are rational. The answer is a little complicated. First of all, one *can* do it. Secondly, for many mathematical purposes, we *need* to do it, or at least know that it can be done. But certainly not for all. Thirdly, the instructor may insist that the answer be given in the form $p+q\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas No, André, I only said that I am sure that $a/b$ can be written as $p + q\sqrt 2$. Sorry if I wasn't direct enough; my real question is in the last paragraph: I am asking whether one **needs to** put $\frac{u+v\sqrt 2}{u'+v'\sqrt 2}$ in the form $\frac{(u+v\sqrt 2)(u'-v'\sqrt 2)}{u'^2-2v'^2}$, or can compute the division directly. Do you know anything about "quadratic Euclidean domains"?

Comment: If you need say $\frac{7+\sqrt{2}}{17+12\sqrt{2}}$ to say $7$ decimal places, you can divide directly on your calculator. There is certainly no need for a preliminary transformation. Actually, the situation even here is a little complicated. If you need to divide by $17-12\sqrt{2}$, then because this is not far from $0$, you will lose accuracy if you divide directly, and preliminary transformation may be useful. However, usually if you want numerical results you can divide directly. With most calculators, fewer key presses are needed to evaluate $\frac{1}{7-2\sqrt{2}}$ directly. (More.)

Comment: In the old days when stuff was done by hand, preliminary transformation was almost always useful. No more! Here I have addressed *numerical* computation. As mentioned earlier, for *theoretical* reasons, it is often necessary to know that the quotient can be expressed as $p+q\sqrt{2}$. And yes, I know about quadratic Euclidean domains. Have taught number theory a fair number of times!

Comment: @AndréNicolas That's fine. Anyway, I'm writing a modified version of the Euclidean algorithm, as an exercise from my book, that accepts numbers of the form $u + v\sqrt 2$ as input, and also divisors of the same form. Thus I don't have to do too many numerical computations, in the sense that the algorithm leaves a number $u + v\sqrt 2$ as output(the **GCD** of $a$ and $b$) The problem is when I have to divide $a$ and $b$, I'm not sure whether write "Compute $a/b$" or (as it's written in the answer section of the book) "Compute $a/b = a(u'-v'\sqrt 2)(u'^2-2v'^2)$. Is that really necessary?

Comment: I am not sure it is absolutely necessary, but you will need a *remainder* of the right form for the division algorithm.

Comment: I think the remainder $r$ has the same form $u''' + v'''\sqrt 2$, because $r = a - qb$, where $q$, as said before, has initially the form $p + q\sqrt 2$, but then one needs to make $q = u'' + v''\sqrt 2$ (where $u''$ and $v''$ are the nearest integers to $p$ and $q$), otherwise the algorithm is not valid

Comment: Precisely. One can *imagine* there may be a way to determine these "nearest integers" in some other, conceivably faster way, but rationalizing the denominator definitely works.

Comment: Ok, just now I start getting confused... So, shall I leave "Compute $a/b = a(u'-v'\sqrt 2)/(u'^2-2v'^2)$"?

Comment: @AndréNicolas All right, now it's all clearer: I reflected a bit on this problem, and basically there are no other important doubts. Thank you André!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\left( u'+v'\sqrt{2} \right)\left( u'-v'\sqrt{2} \right)=u'^2-2v'^2$$

Thus

$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{\left(u+v\sqrt{2}\right) \left( u'-v'\sqrt{2} \right)}{u'^2-2v'^2}$$

This way, the top has the form $m+n\sqrt{2}$ with $m,n$ integers, and the denominator is another integer $l$. Thus, you $p=\frac{m}{l}$ and $q=\frac{n}{l}$.

Important, for integers, $u'^2-2v'^2=0$ if and only if $u'=v'=0$.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, however, I was mainly asking if the division was valid with the $\sqrt 2$ in the denominator, and if it was necessary to reduce. In fact I've only known this method to divide $a$ and $b$